# background change every second

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I need to make background change every second. if i use setinterval. the background changes too fast.

here's my code:

```
    const { url, id, isButtonPrev, isButtonNext } = useOwnSelector(state => state.sliderReducer);
    const img = useRef<HTMLImageElement>(null);
    const dispatch = useOwnDispatch();
```

Here's function which chang background

```
    const setBackGround = (index: number | null = null) => {
    console.log(index)
    if(img.current) {
        img.current.src = `${url}${id < 10 ? `0${id}` : `${id}`}.jpg`;

        img.current.onload = () => {
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${img.current?.src})`;
            if (index) dispatch(setId(index));
            dispatch(isButton(''));
        }
    }
    }
```

then I call this function:

```
    setBackGround();
    setInterval(() => {
       setBackGround(id + 1);
    }, 1000);
```

but background change very fast

I also tried to use the useEffect hook. But it didn’t help either

```
   useEffect( () => {
     const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
         setBackGround(id + 1);
     }, 1000);
     return clearInterval(intervalID);
   }, []);
```

Comment: img.src is wrong,

use img.current?.src instead

Answer (score 1):

useRef returns an object like `{current: "value"}`.Therefore, you need to use it as follows.

```
const imgRef = useRef<HTMLImageElement>(null);

if(imgRef.current){
  imgRef.current.src = url;
}
```